# How to use async await when the function in await needs to be looped dynamically

Tags: node.js, async-await

Here is my scenario.

I'm using NodeJS to make API requests.

I need to make an API request to fetch a set of data. I receive a limited set of records with a field called `counter`, which will let me know if I need to make another request to fetch the remaining data (pagination basically).

So I need to make multiple requests to the same API to fetch the total data.

Here is what I have tried. The resolve function is not returning data.

What should be the right syntax to achieve this?

```
 app.post('/api/fetchData', async function(req, res) {

     try {

         var totalData = await getDataFromLoop(token, '');


     } catch (e) {
        console.log('Exception', e);
     } 

 });



 var loopArray = []; 
 function getDataFromLoop(accessToken, counter){


request({
 url: 'API URL',
 auth: {
             'bearer': accessToken
         }
 }, function(err, response) {

    if(err)
    {


    }
    else
    {
           var res_data = JSON.parse(response.body);


             if(res_data.hasOwnProperty('hasMore'))
             {
                       loopArray.push(res_data.data);

                         console.log('One More Loop to go', res_data.offset);

                         getDataFromLoop(accessToken, res_data.offset);

             }
             else
             {
                        console.log('Looping Done');

                        loopArray.push(res_data.data);

                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {


                        resolve(loopArray);

                         });

             }

     }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the Promise outside of the request function call in getDataFromLoop

```
function getDataFromLoop(accessToken, counter){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       request(..., 
        ... 
           if (res_data.hasOwnProperty('hasMore')) {
              ...
              getDataFromLoop(accessToken, res_data.offset).then(resolve)
           } else {
              ...  
              resolve(loopArray)
           }
       )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `async...await`, I guess you can achieve that with a simple `while` loop, like so:

```js
let shouldFetchAgain = true;
let finalData = [];

while (shouldFetchAgain) {
  const data = await fetch('<some_url>');

  shouldFetchAgain = data.currentCount < data.total;

  finalData.push(data.content);
}

// Process `finalData` here.
```

The code snippet above demonstrates how you can leverage `while` loop to decide whether you need to fetch the data again. This looks like a polling technique you're using to fetch paginated data.

Alternatively, you can check out [PollingObserver](https://github.com/motss/nodemod/tree/master/src/polling-observer).

Hope this helps you.